# How to reduce size of contract?

Tags: solidity

I am getting the below message:

,Warning: Contract code size is 28837 bytes and exceeds 24576 bytes (a limit introduced in Spurious Dragon). This contract may not be deployable on Mainnet. Consider enabling the optimizer (with a low "runs" value!), turning off revert strings, or using libraries.

I think it is due to:

```
function fetchPatientProfile(PatientProfileData storage self, address key) internal view returns (Patient memory) {
    Patient memory patientProfile = self.patientProfiles[key]; // get value
    return patientProfile;
}
```

Is there a better way to create a fetch from storage variable?

I'm creating profiles from the below function, which calls a library:

```
function createPatientProfile(Patient calldata profile) external onlyOwner {
    require(patientProfiles.addPatientProfile(profile));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good link that might help. https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/downsizing-contracts-to-fight-the-contract-size-limit/

NOTE: Make sure you are using solidity optimizer.

Comment: I separated the functions into library, but what if the library is now exceeding the size?

Comment: You can have two or more libraries (External Libraries)